# Unzipping files using winzip in command prompt

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, winzip

I am trying to unzip the files from an archive called wz_test at the command prompt, using the following command:

> wzunzip -d c:\wz_test.zip c:\new

I am not able to unzip because it's saying that the file was blocked due to security zones.  I tried to unblock the zip file but it's not working.  It's not letting me to unblock it even though I have administrator rights.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the error?

Answer (score 1):

Place the ZIP file in quotes.

```
wzunzip -d "c:\wz_test.zip" c:\new
```

I had the same problem, (with underscore in my file name,) by doing the above, i solved my problem.

Let us know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

That may contains password if you have that password the use option -s. 
wzunzip -s123456789 c:\wz_test.zip c:\new

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem.  The underscores (blanks in windows) was not processing correctly.  I put the files in a directory without an underscore and it worked fine.

(I'm executing WZUnZip in an execute process in a n SSIS package.)

Answer (score 0):

The above did not solve my problem. I re-processed my files and the error reappeared.

The error is caused when files are received by Email or downloaded from the Internet.  Windows does its own settings here.

- Right click your ZIP File
- go to properties
- click on "Unblock"

once you have done the above, the file will unzip.